# Strange characters in APPLE Software License Agreement

Tags: software-update, internationalization, license

I have been getting notifications to do a software update. The Software License Agreement has some strange characters. I am not sure if it would be ok to accept it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to Applications > Font Book and doing File > Restore Standard Fonts and restarting.